# Desinstalar navegador pelo console

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, console

Estou tentando usar o comando `delete navigator;`. Ele até me retorna `true` mas não acontece nada no javascript para desinstalar o navegador Chrome. Por algum motivo não está dando certo, alguém poderia me ajudar?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

O comando `delete navigator;` não "desinstalar" o navegador, o `delete` serve para deletar variáveis e níveis de objetos literais por exemplo. No seu caso você está tentando deletar a global nativa `navigator`, e não está funcionando pois o navegador não permite que você remova essa variável.

Comment: Ótima resposta.

Answer (score 2):

Como @DiegoLopesLima disse o delete serve para remover variáveis e objetos, você pode até sobrescrever a referencia navigator mas não deletar o objeto associado a ela.   sugiro que você de uma olhada em:

> http://www.codecademy.com/
>
> https://www.codeschool.com/

A resposta para essa [`Pergunta`](http://www.guj.com.br/14716/historico) feita no GUJ talves seja util pra você.

Comment: Obrigado Mr Tuyoshi.. é que o código que eu meti estava dando erro aí eu tenter meter outro mas não adiantou nada. mas mesmo assim obrigado